# Messed up Eclipse window layout

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, ide

I accidently messed up the default eclipse layout now I can't get it back the way it used to be. [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzS5r.png) is a picture. What really annoys me is that eclipse now is taking up unnecessary space at the top. What I want gone, but can't get rid of is the bar all the to the right with "Java" in it. Right clicking won't help at all. Second, I want to get rid of the bar left to this "Java"-bar. As you can see it doesn't really have ANY FUNCTIONALITY AT ALL(??). To get rid of this strange bar is the most important thing since this will move up "Java" and Quicksearch to the placement above.

Edit: Just so to be clarify, [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mw78A.png) bar is what I mean which woul solve everything.

Actually, the most helpful thing would be to restore the whole Eclipse layout to default. I have tried Window->Restore Perspective but it doesn't help me :(

Thanks!

Comment: Which plug-in of eclipse you are using? You can try different perspective from options.

Comment: How do I find what plugin I use? Or do you mean version? Version: 4.2.1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

right mouse click on the perspective(top-right "Java") and select Reset. This will fix the perspective.

EDIT: It seems to be a [bug](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/412184/) in Eclipse Juno. A suggestion is to delete the `workbench.xmi` file, but it doesn't work for everybody...

So If it doesnt work, you have to install your eclipse again.

Comment: That will fix the perspective, but it doesn't seem I have problem with the perspective. If you look at the picture I have problem with closing an "invisible bar"

Comment: I tried it on eclipse 3.8 and my solution resets also the toolbar

Comment: And how do I reset the toolbar?

Comment: I marked you up for the reset tip, but your advise to re-install eclipse is not recommended. You can easily delete the configuration by deleting the workspace folder. If you have projects in the workspace you want to retain, delete the '.metadata' subdirectory.

Answer (score 1):

There are different things you might try:

1. You should be able to drag and drop the bar to a location where it
   automatically docks and does not disturb you (e.g. at the bottom)
2. Right click the emtpy bar and choose "hide toolbar"
3. If everything fails: Delete your eclipse installation and load a new one. Don't delete your workspace and point the new installation to your current workspace. You will have all your projects as they are now.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, until this bug will be resolved, you can edit eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.platform_4.2.1.v201209141800\css\e4_classic_winxp.css.
Append following code.

```
.MToolBar.Draggable {
    handle-image:  url(./winXPHandle.png);
}

.MToolControl.Draggable {
    handle-image:  url(./winXPHandle.png);
}
```

Source: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=389594#c4

Answer (score 0):

I had to click on reset for all my perspectives, then exit eclipse, and re-open it. Worked for me.